# Change the resource limits (ulimit / rlimit) of a running process

Tags: linux, ulimit

I have a long-running process that is hitting a resource limit, such as the maximum number of open files.

I don't want to kill it.

Usually, you'd do:

```
(stop service)
ulimit -n <new limit>
(start service)
```

Is there a way to avoid having to stop and start the service and increase the limits?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've figured it out.

On some kernels (e.g. 2.6.32+), at least on CentOS/RHEL, you can change the resource limits of a running process using `/proc/<pid>/limits`, e.g.:

```
$ grep "open files" /proc/23052/limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
Max open files            1024                 4096                 files
```

To change the maximum open files to a soft limit of 4096, hard limit of 8192:

```
echo -n "Max open files=4096:8192" > /proc/23052/limits
```

This gives:

```
$ grep "open files" /proc/23052/limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
Max open files            4096                 8192                 files
```

Note the `-n` in **`echo -n`** - without that, you'll get an "`invalid argument`" error.

### The above doesn't always work, so

Another option is [`prlimit`](http://karelzak.blogspot.com/2012/01/prlimit1.html) command, introduced with `util-linux 2.21` allows you to read and change the limits of running processes.

This is a followup to the writable `/proc/<pid>/limits`, which was not integrated in mainline kernel. This solution should work.

```
$ prlimit  --nofile --output RESOURCE,SOFT,HARD --pid 23052
RESOURCE SOFT HARD
NOFILE   1024 4096
```

Set the limits:

```
$ prlimit --nofile=4096:8192 --pid 23052
```

Confirm:

```
$ prlimit  --nofile --output RESOURCE,SOFT,HARD --pid 23052RESOURCE SOFT HARD
NOFILE   4096 8192
```

```
$ grep "open files" /proc/23052/limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
Max open files            4096                 8192                 files
```